# Paginador en laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola amigos tengo este simple buscador pero quiero implementarle un paginador al poner

```
{!! $creates->links() !!}
```

Me genera el siguiente error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.
```

Habra alguna forma de combinar los dos buscador y paginador

Codigo:

```
$texto = $request->input('texto');
    $creates = create::query()
    ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->get();
    return view('productos.index', compact('creates'));
```

Comment: Que dice la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination)?

Comment: Tu consulta debe terminar en `->paginate();` en lugar de `->get();`, como ya te recomendaron, revisa la documentación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tiene fácil solución, solo hace falta añadir el paginate de la siguiente manera.

```php
$texto = $request->input('texto');
    $creates = create::query()
    ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', "%{$texto}%")
    ->paginate(10);
    return view('productos.index', compact('creates'));
```

También te añado la solución a un posible error que tengas en un futuro y es que al hacer una búsqueda i te devuelva resultados en más de una pagina, al cambiar de pagina se borra la búsqueda i devuelve todos los registros sin filtro de búsqueda.
Para solucionarlo solo hace falta editar el código links de la vista de la siguiente manera.

```php
{{ $creates->appends(request()->input())->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

uso tailwind para mis estilos
mi mi controlador en  index queda así

```html
public function index()
    {
        $datos['registros']=Registro::paginate(5);
        
        return view('Registro.RegistrosIndex', $datos );
    }
```

y en mi html lo llamo asi

```html
<table class="table-borderless">
  <td>
    <tr>
      <a  href="{{$registros->previousPageUrl()}}"
          class="btn bg-gradient-primary w-30 my-4 mb-2">
          <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
          pagina anterior
        </a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        {{ $registros->currentPage()}} 
        /
        {{$registros->lastPage()}}   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <a  href="{{$registros->nextPageUrl()}}" class="btn bg-gradient-primary w-30 my-4 mb-2">
          pagina siguiente
          <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </tr>
    </td>
</table>
```